# Admob Rewarded Video Ads Reporting Zero Revenue for a week

Tags: android, admob, ads, admob-rewardedvideoad, google-ads-data-hub

For a week now, i have added admob rewarded video ads to my app to reward users with a point for each video ads watched. The users are watchig the videos and getting the rewards, but my admob dashboard always shows 0 as revenue.
Check attached picture.[image]

Comment: Same, could you able to solve the issue ?

Comment: Well. i discovered that i was using the test ad unit ID. i replaced it with the real id.